# Integrate a Woocommerce site to another wordpress installation that resides on a different host

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, integration

I'm trying to integrate a woocommerce site to another wordpress site that resides on a different host. The process would be after a user successfully makes a purchase from the woocommerce site (which is a membership plan) a user is then created to the wordpress site which is hosted from a different server. Can you give suggestions on how I can accomplish this requirement. Thanks

Comment: google WordPress REST api

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it.